# Prolog binary list issue

Tags: list, prolog, binary-tree, dcg, failure-slice

I'm working on a binary tree program in Prolog. The specific issue I'm having is with traversals.
Here's what I have :

```
inOrder(bttree(_,L,_),T):-  inOrder(L,T).
inOrder(bttree(N,_,_),T) :- T1 = T, append(T1,N,T).
inOrder(bttree(_,_,R),T):-  inOrder(R,T).
```

I've been querying it with:

```
inOrder(bttree(20,
    bttree(10, bttree(5, nil, nil), bttree(15, nil, nil)) bttree(30)), T).
```

so the output SHOULD be:

```
[5,10,15,20,30];
false.
```

But when I run it, it just returns false.
I'm fairly certain the problem is in my use of append/3, but I simply can't work it out.
If anyone can help, it'd be much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this `T1 = T, append(T1,N,T)` is equivalent to `append(T,N,T)` and doomed to loop...

some corrections...

```
inOrder(nil, []).
inOrder(bttree(N, L, R),T) :-
  inOrder(L, LT),
  inOrder(R, RT),
  append(LT, [N|RT], T).
```

test:

```
?- inOrder(bttree(20, bttree(10, bttree(5,nil,nil), bttree(15,nil,nil)), bttree(30,nil,nil)), T).
T = [5, 10, 15, 20, 30].
```

Comment: @Tom: Note that this solution has quadratic overhead for an inherently linear operation. That is, linear in the size of the tree.

Answer (score 2):

I get rather an infinite loop  for the query (note the missing comma in your original query):

```
?- inOrder(bttree(20,
      bttree(10, bttree(5, nil, nil), bttree(15, nil, nil)), bttree(30)), T).
   loops.
```

And I get the same infinite loop, even after adding goals **`false`** into your program. The resulting program is called a [failure-slice](/questions/tagged/failure-slice):

```
inOrder(bttree(_,L,_),T):- false, inOrder(L,T).
inOrder(bttree(N,_,_),T) :- T1 = T, append(T1,N,T), false.
inOrder(bttree(_,_,R),T):-  false, inOrder(R,T).
```

So this remaining clause alone causes this loop. In fact, any query with a node `bttree/3` will now loop, even

```
 ?- inOrder(bttree(20, nil,nil), T).
    loops.
```

So we need to fix *at least* that remaining visible part.

Not that clauses are read independently of each other, so your first clause reads:

```
inOrder(bttree(_,L,_),T):- inOrder(L,T).
```

So the inorder traversal of a node will be just the inorder traversal of a the left subtree. That does not seem right.

What you actually want is to describe them together. The best way is not to use `append/3` but rather a [dcg](/questions/tagged/dcg):

```
inorder(nil) --> [].
inorder(bttree(N,L,R)) -->
   inorder(L),
   [N],
   inorder(R).
```

Now we get:

```
?- phrase(inorder(bttree(20,
      bttree(10, bttree(5, nil, nil), bttree(15, nil, nil)), bttree(30))), T).
   false.
```

Again, false! But this time it is this `bttree(30)` which should be replaced:

```
?- phrase(inorder(bttree(20,
      bttree(10, bttree(5, nil, nil), bttree(15, nil, nil)), bttree(30,nil,nil))), T).
   T = [5,10,15,20,30].
```

Answer (score 0):

Just in case you *don't* want a dcg:

```
inOrder( nil, [] ).
inOrder( btree( L, N, R ), T ) :- 
    inOrder( L, TL ),
    inOrder( N, TN ),
    inOrder( R, TR ),
    append( TL, TN, TLN ),
    append( TLN, TR, T ).
```

Comment: Do I understand your solution correctly? There is no solution for `inOrder(T, [E|Es])`? So the second argument will always be `[]`?